# Reducing the scope of SQL queries on a NAVISION 2009 R2 report

Tags: sql, microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-business-central

In NAVISION 2009 R2, I have a report which iterate on 3 tables :

- Service Header : 82 266 items / 120512 Ko
- Service Line : 311 117 items  / 720 352 Ko
- Service Ledger Entry : **2 293 754 items / 2 453 568 Ko**

I'm exporting about 10 000 Headers and 50 000 Lines.

From **SQL Server Profiler**, I see that NAVISION makes :

- 1 query on Headers

  `SELECT  * FROM "database_name"."dbo"."company_name$Service Header"`
- 10 000 queries on Lines (using a DataItemLink property)

  `SELECT  * FROM "database_name"."dbo"."company_name$Service Line"`
- 50 000 queries on Ledger Entries (using a SETRANGE + SETFILTER procedure)

  `SELECT  * FROM "database_name"."dbo"."company_name$Service Line"`

Due to the size of the Service Ledger entry table, those queries takes about 300ms each (according to the StmtCompleted events), so **more than 4 hours** in total.

As I'm using a limited number of attributes from the Ledger entry tables,

**Is there a way to avoid the `SELECT *` request by default by NAVISION** and instead to list the necessary attributes?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to limit the fields fetched by Nav but here is an experimental idea, I once used it for an integration project, it goes like this:

1. Create a view in SQL Server for each table (Or even a combined view)
2. Save the view with Nav object name style: [CompanyName]$[ViewNAme]
3. Create a Tables in Nav and set the property "LinkedObject" to true
4. Save the table with exact same name as the View without the company name: ViewName
5. Add the fields you want with the same name they have in the view to the Nav table and save it.

Now use these Tables ("LinkedObject - View") in your report.